# How can I prevent getting toothpaste in my eye?

Tags: personal-care

Sometimes when I put toothpaste on my toothbrush, I get somehow a drop of toothpaste in my eye, even though my toothbrush is more than 50 cm from my eye. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using a lot less toothpaste. In contrast to what's commonly visualised in toothpaste commercials, a **pea sized drop** in the middle should be [sufficient](https://www.koiscenter.com/patient-education/smile/how-much-toothpaste-should-i-use/) (see also [here](https://www.health.com/condition/oral-health/how-much-toothpaste-should-you-use) and [here](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-02-08/are-you-using-too-much-toothpaste/10792828)):

> **A Pea Sized Amount for Adults**
>
> For adults or anyone that’s old enough to brush their teeth
> independently (including children that can rinse well and floss on
> their own,) only a pea sized amount of toothpaste is necessary.
> Anything more than this is unnecessary.

Just depositing that pea in place removes the need to streak the toothpaste tube across the brush, which also completely stops the brush hairs from spattering.

Answer (score 3):

If you are squeezing the toothpaste onto the brush while moving the tube away from you, the bristles can flick the paste into your face.

If instead, you use a sideways motion to load the brush, the paste shouldn't flick in the direction of your face.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like [this](https://www.thehouseofmouth.com.au/product/flipper-toothpaste-squirter-whale-pinki/):

[image]

Might look silly but from what I can see, it would prevent any unwanted toothpaste in your eyes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put on protection goggles (e.g. swimming goggles) and when you're finished brushing your teeth, clean them with water.